# Changing lock screen background programmatically

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-wallpaper

I am trying to change the lock screen background image from my app but am unable to figure out how to do it. I succeeded in changing the home screen wallpaper using WallPaperManager, but could not find a source to do the same for the lock screen. I know apps such as QuickPic and the stock Gallery do this, so how can I implement it?

Here is the code I used to change the home screen:

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bm);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can someone who has implemented this please point me in the right direction to do this with my app?

Comment: Thats not a right answer so only I have posted question here. Many apps do that so therr must be a way for this.

Comment: @T3KBAU5 I agree with OP, I have seen apps such as Google Play Music do this, and OP mentioned a few in the question. While this may not have been possible in 2010, I suspect there is a way to do it now.